# Error on connection between LoopbackJS and PostgreSQL when making a request

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, loopbackjs

I instaled postgresql and set up a new user and made a new database with tables that I needed. Also I instaled loopback and setup an API server. Connected the API and the database via loopback-connector-postgresql. And when I go to localhost:3000/explorer and try to make a get request I get an error  `"message": "relation \"public.acl\" does not exist"` . I tried to search this error, with no luck, I am new to Loopback JS. Here is the full error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "name": "error",
    "message": "relation \"public.acl\" does not exist",
    "length": 109,
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "code": "42P01",
    "position": "93",
    "file": "parse_relation.c",
    "line": "1159",
    "routine": "parserOpenTable",
    "stack": "error: relation \"public.acl\" does not exist\n    at Connection.parseE (C:\\Users\\Adomas\\Documents\\ActualDocs\\Projects\\ReminderApp\\node_modules\\pg\\lib\\connection.js:553:11)\n    at Connection.parseMessage (C:\\Users\\Adomas\\Documents\\ActualDocs\\Projects\\ReminderApp\\node_modules\\pg\\lib\\connection.js:378:19)\n    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\\Users\\Adomas\\Documents\\ActualDocs\\Projects\\ReminderApp\\node_modules\\pg\\lib\\connection.js:119:22)\n    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)\n    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)\n    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)\n    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)\n    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)\n    at TCP.onread (net.js:597:20)"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the problem is because you could not create the database tables for loopback's build in models. ACL is one of them.

You could follow the instructions on this [link](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Creating-a-database-schema-from-models.html)

Copy pasting the text here so it is easy for you to find

> To create tables for LoopBack built-in models, follow this procedure:
>
> 1. Follow the basic procedure in [Attaching models to data sources](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Attaching-models-to-data-sources.html) to
>      change from the in-memory data source to the  database you want to
>      use.
> 2. Create server/create-lb-tables.js file with the following:
>
>    ```
>    var server = require('./server'); 
>    var ds = server.dataSources.db; 
>    var lbTables = ['User', 'AccessToken', 'ACL', 'RoleMapping', 'Role'];
>    ds.automigrate(lbTables, function(er) {   
>       if (er) throw er;  
>       console.log('Loopback tables [' + lbTables + '] created in ',ds.adapter.name);   
>    ds.disconnect(); 
>    });
>    ```
> 3. Run the script manually:
>
>    ```
>    $ cd server 
>    $ node create-lb-tables.js
>    ```